# How to pass the validation of typescript in function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to write a simple helper function to pass the validation of type, here are the code.

```js
interface User {
  type: "user";
  name: string;
  age: number;
  occupation: string;
}

interface Admin {
  type: "admin";
  name: string;
  age: number;
  role: string;
}

// a person either is a user or admin ?
export type Person = User | Admin;

export const persons: Person[] = [
  {
    type: "user",
    name: "Max",
    age: 25,
    occupation: "FE",
  },
  {
    type: "admin",
    name: "Jane",
    age: 32,
    role: "Administrator",
  },
  {
    type: "user",
    name: "Bill",
    age: 23,
    occupation: "BE",
  },
  {
    type: "admin",
    name: "Bruce",
    age: 64,
    role: "DBA",
  },
];

export function isAdmin(person: Person) {
  return person.type === "admin";
}

// because we are using copy on write ?　so the typescript can not receive the variable being validate ?
export const isUser = (person: Person) => {
  return person.type === "user";
};

export function logPerson(person: Person) {
  let extaInformation: string = "";
  //  This doesn't work !!!
  //   if (isAdmin(person)) {
  //     extaInformation = person.role;
  //   }
  //   if (isUser(person)) {
  //     extaInformation = person.occupation;
  //   }

  // this works
  if (person.type === "admin") {
    extaInformation = person.role;
  }
  if (person.type === "user") {
    extaInformation = person.occupation;
  }
  console.log(` - ${person.name}, ${person.age}, ${extaInformation}`);
}

console.log("Admins:");
persons.filter(isAdmin).forEach(logPerson);

console.log("Users:");
persons.filter(isUser).forEach(logPerson);
```

I am trying to figure out why this doesn't work since the object is passed by refernce, so technically it should pass the validation. How should I write the best practice when it comes to type validation in this kind of situation ?

Comment: Control flow analysis doesn't propagate outside of functions; if you want to use a boolean-returning function as a type guard, you need to annotate it as a custom type guard function, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgAV4m).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104696/how-to-pass-the-validation-of-typescript-in-function-parameter#comment132536617_75104696) @jcalz Surely this is a duplicate, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

1. Create `PersonData` and include all redundant data in there:

```
type PersonData = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    type: "user" | "admin";
};
```

2. Make all your `Persons` extend `PersonData`.

```
export type User = {
    type: "user";
    occupation: string;
} & PersonData;

export type Admin = {
    type: "admin";
    role: string;
} & PersonData;
```

3. Update your functions to include the `person is x` constraint:

```
export const isAdmin = (person: Person): person is Admin =>
    person.type === "admin";

export const isUser = (person: Person): person is User =>
    person.type === "user";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you help me understand why we need to structure the type this way, and it's advantage over my original writing? Thanks again for helping!

Comment: Well, using the `&` operator allows you to extend your types in a pretty similar way that it would be with a class, and it helps Typescript to determine which fields go where. Note that is not strictly necessary to do it, you can also keep your models as is. In the other hand, the `person is Admin` and `person is User` constraints are the only way Typescript can know you are using this function for type checking, otherwise is just a regular function that returns a boolean.